# The gizmo line display is strange

Tags: 3d-view, interface, gizmo

I am using a translation.
sorry for the inconvenience.

I am using Blender 2.83.
The gizmo line display is strange.
I'm seeing a bug like the image, but I'm not sure why.
I would be very happy if someone could give me a solution.

Thank you.

[image]